# group and count the result from LEN and alias

Tags: sql, count

I have column with data like below.

```
A1
A2
A3
A1/B1
A1/B2
A1/B1/C1
```

I have SQL query like this to count total number of each group by /.

Which the data does not has / is 3 ,has one / is 2 ,has two / is 1

```
select ( len(colA) - len(replace(colA, '/', '')) ) as num_slashes 
from DBO.table1
```

result returned as below, 
how to count 0 has 3 counts, 1 has 2 counts, 2 has 1 count?

```
0
0
0
1
1
2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `count distinct` for this requirement. I'm using `subquery` to avoid repeating `len(colA) - len(replace(colA, '/', ''))`

```
select count(distinct case when t1.num_slashes < 1 then 0 else num_slashes end) as num_slashes
from (select 
     (len(colA) - len(replace(colA, '/', ''))) as num_slashes 
    from DBO.table1) t1
```

Answer (score 1):

Add grouping to your query by the number of slashes (evaluated within a subquery) and count how many rows each group has to present it:

```
select 
 num_slashes
 count(*) as count_appearances
from (
  select 
    len(colA) - len(replace(colA, '/', '')) as num_slashes
  from DBO.table1
) t
group by num_slashes
```

If you need additional sorting based on the number of slashes then add `order by num_slashes` at the end of the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat the expression in the `select` and `group by`;

```
select ( len(colA) - len(replace(colA, '/', '')) ) as num_slashes,
       count(*) 
from DBO.table1 
group by ( len(colA) - len(replace(colA, '/', '')) )
```

Some databases allow you to use aliases for the `group by`, in which case:

```
select ( len(colA) - len(replace(colA, '/', '')) ) as num_slashes,
       count(*) 
from DBO.table1 
group by num_slashes;
```